# how to put a Location object in Parcelable

Tags: java, android

I have a Location object in one of my other Venue object that implements Parcelable. How do I serialize this correctly in my writeToParcel method implementation? So here's some code:

```
public class Venue implements Parcelable{
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public Location location;
    public String city;
    public String state;
    public String country;
    public String postalCode;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel desc, int flags) {
        desc.writeString(id);
        desc.writeString(state);
        desc.writeString(name);
        desc.writeString(address);
        desc.writeString(postalCode);
        desc.writeString(country);
        desc.writeString(city);
        //I am still missing on a way to serialize my Location object here
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear what you're asking. What have you tried so far?

Comment: edited with some code sample, hope it helps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here your have a snippet how to serialize parcable objects into your own parcel.

```
Location location;

public void writeToParcel(Parcel desc, int flags) {
    location.writeToParcel(desc, flags);
    /* do your other parcel stuff here */
}

public void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    location=Location.CREATOR.createFromParcel(in);
    /* do your other parcel stuff here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about lists/arrays? Are you supposed to store the size, or how are you supposed to deal with them?

Answer (score 1):

`location = in.readParcelable(Location.class.getClassLoader());` also works.