# Serializing android.location.Location with Gson

Tags: java, android, serialization, gson, parcelable

In my Android app, I would like to store some locations. I retrieve these locations with Android´s provider and get instances of [android.location.Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html).

To store data, I serialize my objects to JSON using [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide). However, I run into some Exception when I manipulate the retrieved Location objects. Here is the stacktrace I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at android.os.Parcel.nativeAppendFrom(Native Method)
        at android.os.Parcel.appendFrom(Parcel.java:431)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1679)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
        at android.location.Location.writeToParcel(Location.java:908)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1048)
        at com.example.app.bean.PostExtraData.writeToParcel(PostExtraData.java:58)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1285)
        at com.example.app.bean.Post.writeToParcel(Post.java:166)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1285)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1204)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
```

As we can see, it happens when serializing the Parcelable Location to communicate between Activities. It happens only for Location objects deserialized from JSON. The code causing this in PostExtraData is :

```
private ArrayList<Location> locations;

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
  parcel.writeTypedList(locations);
}
```

Apparently there is something wrong with Location. And actually, I could get to see a representation of the Location instance once it is deserialized from JSON:

```
Location[fused 65.966700,-18.533300 acc=1 et=+23m6s700ms alt=15.044444 vel=0.0 bear=0.0 {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=-1196422336]}]
```

My question is, what are my options to serialize properly my Location instances? Is my only option to write a specific deserializer for android.location.Location?

Comment: Is there a reason for doing it this way? Have you looked into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112565/how-to-put-a-location-object-in-parcelable

Comment: @zgc7009 Thanks I was looking for this kind of question for some time. Unfortunately it did not change anyhting (and I did not find how I am supposed to deal with lists/arrays the other way).